# Buying extensions

Tags: extensions, magento-connect

I want to know, we are updating to Magento 2, do we need to pay for the extensions we bought on magento 1 if they are available on magento 2?

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** This does not depend on magento. It depends on each extension provider.
**Long version:**
Magento 1 and 2 are 2 different platforms.
And so are the extensions with the same functionality.
I guess it depends on how the extension providers want to distribute their modules for Magento 2.
Most likely you will have to pay for the new magento 2 modules unless the extension provider has a policy to give you free upgrades to M2 modules.
Also, keep in mind that some of the extension providers might not have a M2 equivalent for an M1 extension.